# Git pre-push hook not working

Tags: git

I have placed a file inside .git/hooks named pre-push.sh

I am not making any check, just want to echo some error while pushing to the remote. Below is the .sh file content

```
protected_branch='test'
echo $protected_branch
exit 1
```

However it is still allowing to push changes without throwing any error. Need help to find where am i making mistake?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The name of the hook must be exactly `pre-push` (not `pre-push.sh`, not `pre-push.exe`, not `pre-push.py` ...)

Also: the hook should be executable, otherwise it will be ignored

```
chmod u+x .git/hooks/pre-push
```

Answer (score 7):

I just ran into the same problem and had a proper name for the hook BUT also had to make sure it was executable

```
chmod 766 .git/hooks/pre-push
```

fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

`pre-push.sh` isn't a valid hook name. Instead this needs to be placed on the server as a `pre-receive` hook.

Comment: Here is the no. of sample files for pre-push https://github.com/raven/git-prepush-recipes and as per documentation it works on client-side before push

Comment: OK - never used one. Always run things server side. Try without the `.sh` extension.

Comment: @Flash that github link is broken.

Comment: Answer is only partially correct. `pre-push` is a valid hook: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks under "Other Client Hooks"

Comment: Downvoted for being wrong.